# SIMD matrix multiplication for a rectangular matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-multiplication, sse, simd

Is it possible to do a generic matrix multiplication for a rectangular matrix using SIMD instructions. So far all the examples that i came across through online are of square matrix     ( N X N) and the N is know. I understand that SIMD instructions has nothing to do with matrices size and its more of a parallel computing.

Is it a good idea or Is it possible to have a matrix multiplication using SIMD instruction of size M X N where are M, N are set in the constructor of class.

```
class MatrixMN {
  MatrixMN(size_t rows, size_t cols) {..}
  MatrixMN operator*(const MatrixMN& m) const {
    // check for dimension match

    // USE SIMD INSTRUCTION TO PERFORM MATRIX MULTIPLICATION ??
  }
};
```

The Matrix is double precision, and since we are using older hardware we have only access to `__m128d`. Which result in loading two doubles

Comment: is the matrix element single or double precission?

Comment: Yes, SIMD works for rectangular matrices; check out any open-source BLAS implementation that uses SIMD.

Comment: Do you know the dimensions at compile time? Do you have any guarantee on the dimensions? E.g., can the inner dimension be odd? Looking at existing BLAS implementations as Peter suggested might help, but that usually gets complicated quickly, e.g., due to blocking, loop-unrolling, ...

Comment: @chtz, The MatrixMN class expects no. of rows and cols  as an argument in the constructor and can't be changed in the future.  Yes we know Matrix dimensions before the matrix multiplication.  Yes, Inner dimension can be odd.  Are you referring this GitHub page ? https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS

Comment: I was not referring to any specific BLAS implementation -- I personally would recommend using Eigen (but I'm admittedly biased). Asking for software recommendations is off-topic here, and as-is I think the question is too broad.